# Translate sql script into tidyverse format

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, sqldf

I am trying to rewrite my former colleague's script from `sqldf` into `tidyverse`. I couldn't follow this chunk. Two data frames named "data" and "Stt_nm" were joined, but I do not get why he used two selects. Perhaps I am missing something here.

```
output = sqldf(
  paste0(
    "select a.date,b.name,sum(a.weigh) as rch
     from (select distinct date,ID,IndID,Station_id,weigh from data) as a
          left join Stt_nm as b on a.Station_id=b.Station
     where a.date between ",
     startdate,
     " and ",
     enddate,
     "
     group by a.date,b.name"
  )
)
```

Comment: The `SELECT` inside the parenthesis is to retrieve `DISTINCT` records from `data`.  The `LEFT JOIN` is to populate the station name from `Stt_nm`.  Now that might not be the best approach, but that's what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I can't check for sure without a reproducible example, but I think that should do it :

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  select(date, ID, IndID, Station_id, weigh) %>% 
  left_join(Stt_nm, by="Station") %>%
  filter(date <= startdate & date >= enddate) %>%
  group_by(date, name) %>%
  summarize(rch = sum(weigh))
```

Comment: FWIW, you can use `between(date, startdate, enddate)` in the filter statement as an alternative.